# How to add header file for PIC24F08KL401 in MPLAB on MAC

Tags: pic, mplab, mplabx

How can I add header file for PIC24F08KL401 in MPLAB X IDE on MAC?

I have found few tutorials how \ where to find these files ('PIC24F08KL401.h') for example on windows, but none on how to do it on MAC OS.

Comment: does "#include <PIC24F08KL401.h>" not work for you? It should if your XC16 compiler was installed correctly. Although you shouldn't even need to be so specific. "#include <pic.h>" should work if your project is set up correctly as this will use the project settings to select the appropriate processor file.

Comment: It does not, when I hold command for example and try to click on that to navigate to the actual file nothing happens, like the file is not linked correctly. 

But for some other header files which are added automatically I can do that, for example for `#include <xc.h>`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I can do that with just `#include <pic.h>` still PIC newbie :) thanks for the tip, I will try that.

Comment: I don't have XC16 installed on the PC I'm using, so I don't know if the "PIC24F08KL401.h" file you're trying to open even exists. Its possible you're being too specific - the isn't necessarily an individual file for every single variant of every PIC.

Comment: I tried with some more generic PIC like PIC16F877A and I had the same issue, so not sure, maybe if I just use PIC.h it would be enough.

Comment: Tip: go to Window -> PIC Memory Views -> Configuration bits. A panel will open with all fuses for the PIC, set them appropriately for your board (e.g. OSC, Watchdog, etc.). Then click generate code. It will generate boiler code with all the fuses for given PIC and include xc.h.

Comment: I did that, and that's how I get xc.h included, but I didn't know that I don't have to explicitly include my pic header file.

Comment: I believe this is a fairly new "feature." ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the XC16 compiler family, all you need is:

```
#include <xc.h>
```

... since inside it, there's nothing more than lots of #ifdefs for every possible part!

```
/*
 *  xc.h 
 *
 *  Generic include file for XC16
 *
 *  Copyright 2012 Microchip Technology
 */

#if defined(__PIC24EP128GP202__)
#include <p24EP128GP202.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP128GP204__)
#include <p24EP128GP204.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP128GP206__)
#include <p24EP128GP206.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP128MC202__)
#include <p24EP128MC202.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP128MC204__)
#include <p24EP128MC204.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP128MC206__)
#include <p24EP128MC206.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP256GP202__)
#include <p24EP256GP202.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP256GP204__)
#include <p24EP256GP204.h>
#endif

#if defined(__PIC24EP256GP206__)
#include <p24EP256GP206.h>
#endif

/* ...etc etc and so on */
```

This of course is conditional on having a properly set-up project within MPLABX and a properly set-up compiler.

The project setup will take care of defining the appropriate __PIC24xxxxxxxxx__ definition for the target part.

On Windows, the device-specific .h files are in

```
\vX.XX\support\family\h
```

where vX.XX is the compiler version, and family is the part family (PIC24E, PIC24F, PIC24H, DSPIC30F, DSPIC33E, DSPIC33F).

In each of those subfolders is a family-generic header file: for example

```
\v1.26\support\dsPIC33E\h\p33Exxxx.h
```

which, much like xc.h, is nothing but #ifdefs and #includes - only for that specific family, of course.

Comment: You shouldn't accept the answer so quickly. It's considered good practice to wait 24 hours or so to stimulate discussion and see if more answers arise.

Comment: Ok, as you suggested, I will wait to see if there's any comment how to find these files on MAC. :)